# Hide Visibility Option From WordPress Publish Metabox

Tags: pages, wp-admin

I want to hide visibility option on publishbox for PAGE post_type like you see in red square on the below picture.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
function wpseNoVisibility() {
  echo '<style>div#visibility.misc-pub-section.misc-pub-visibility{display:none}</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpseNoVisibility');
```

to `functions.php` of your active theme.

Needless to say, the preferred method, would be to add above code to `functions.php` of the child theme.

**Update**

Unfortunately, the above solution will not limit this change to pages only. We'll have to determine, if we add, or edit page, first. The following code will fix it:

```
function wpseNoVisibility() {
  echo '<style>div#visibility.misc-pub-section.misc-pub-visibility{display:none}</style>';
}

function wpseCurrentScreenAction($current_screen) {
    if ('page' == $current_screen->post_type && 'post' == $current_screen->base) {
        add_action('admin_head', 'wpseNoVisibility');
    }
}
add_action('current_screen', 'wpseCurrentScreenAction');
```