# Hide Some Fields of Post Submit box

Tags: css

Currently i used this code to hide 1.Status 2.Visibility and 3.Published option from Publish box but these code is not working on my wordpress version 5.8..please help me to solve this problem

```
 function hide_publishing_actions(){
    global $post;
    if($pagenow == post.php){
        echo '
            <style type="text/css">
                #misc-publishing-actions,
                #minor-publishing-actions{
                    display:none;
                }
            </style>
        ';
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
```

i want to hide these 3 option
[image: publsih]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on function.php

```
function wpseNoVisibility() {
  echo '<style>div#visibility.misc-pub-section.misc-pub-visibility{display:none}</style>';
}

function wpseCurrentScreenAction($current_screen) {
    if ('page' == $current_screen->post_type && 'post' == $current_screen->base) {
        add_action('admin_head', 'wpseNoVisibility');
    }
}

add_action('current_screen', 'wpseCurrentScreenAction');
```

Source - [Original Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307736/hide-visibility-option-from-wordpress-publish-metabox)

Comment: already tried this code but not working..

Comment: Do you Have any other Idea to hide these fields.

Comment: Why not to try Adminimize plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If using css was enough than you can do this

```
add_action('admin_head', 'bt_hide_publish_options');
function bt_hide_publish_options () {
    global $pagenow;

    if (!in_array($pagenow, ['post-new.php', 'post.php'])) return;
?>
<style>
    #submitdiv #minor-publishing {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<?php
}
```

Add this to your `functions.php` and thats it

This code

```
if (!in_array($pagenow, ['post-new.php', 'post.php'])) return;
```

Will check if you are in post, either a new post or an existing one, if you are not in any of those this code will not execute

Comment: css is worked for me thank You Soo Much